# Python multiprocessing Process not putting functions on own process/core

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to get my script to run over multiple cores. When I start the script it works but only seems to run on one core. I am running this on a Raspberry Pi 3 b+ with 4 cores, but only one is being used when I check using top.

I have tried both Pool and Process from the multiprocessing module. I do not have a programming background but have written basic scrips with Python before, though this is the first time trying to use multiprocessing.

Sorry for sharing all this code but I think its the best way to show what I have tried.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process

import cv2

import face_pi_helper as fph


def put_frame_on_q(q_vid_cap, vid_cap):
    for i in range(5):
        frame = fph.fetch_frame(vid_cap)
    q_vid_cap.put(frame)


def detect_from_q(q_vid_cap, q_detections, net):
    print(fph.time_stamp(), "[INFO] starting detect from q...")
    while True:
        frame = q_vid_cap.get()
        if frame is None: 
            print(fph.time_stamp(), "[WARNING] No frame")
        else:
            detections = tuple(fph.detect(frame, net))
            d = detections[1]
            for f in d:
                conf = float(f[2])
                if conf > 0.9:
                    print(fph.time_stamp(), "[INFO] face found")

            q_detections.put(detections)


def identify_from_q(q_detections,
        vid_cap,
        known_face_encodings,
        known_face_names,
        q_vid_cap
        ):
    print(fph.time_stamp(), "[INFO] starting identify from q...")
    while True:
        detections = q_detections.get()
        if detections is None: 
            print(fph.time_stamp(), "[WARNING] No detections")
        else:
            frame = detections[0]
            fph.identify(
                frame,
                detections[1],
                known_face_encodings,
                known_face_names
                )

        put_frame_on_q(q_vid_cap, vid_cap)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    topology = "models/intel/face-detection-retail-0004.xml"
    weights = "models/intel/face-detection-retail-0004.bin"
    image = "images/adam.jpg"
    db_file = "data/allstars_faces_plus.json"

    print(fph.time_stamp(), "[INFO] starting app...")

    net = fph.load_model(topology, weights)
    known_face_encodings, known_face_names = fph.load_face_db(db_file)

    q_vid_cap = mp.Queue(1)
    q_detections = mp.Queue(1)

    vid_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    put_frame_on_q(q_vid_cap, vid_cap)

    p_detect = Process(
        target = detect_from_q,
        args = (q_vid_cap, q_detections, net, ))
    print(fph.time_stamp(), "[INFO] starting detect from q process...")
    p_detect.start()

    p_identify = Process(
        target = identify_from_q,
        args = (
            q_detections,
            vid_cap,
            known_face_encodings,
            known_face_names,
            q_vid_cap,
            )
        )
    print(fph.time_stamp(),
        "[INFO] starting identify from q process..."
        )
    p_identify.start()

    p_detect.join()
    p_identify.join()
```

I would expect this to run on 3 cores but it only runs on 1.

Comment: How do you know it's only running one one core?

Comment: Hi @RolandSmith. I monitor the resources of the device and can see only one python process running and using only a single core  of the four (25% of total usage, 100% of one).

Comment: What I suspect is that you have problems because you've commented out the `join` calls. As soon as the child processes are started, your parent process exits.

Comment: The result is the same with `join` uncommented, I have also tried only commenting out one or the other. :(

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing all the commented-out code to make it more readable.

Comment: That is a lot of code and hardly any of it is relevant for multiprocessing. Please reduce your code to a *minimal* verifiable example that does not require people to grok all the unrelated domain code. Using a simple ``time.sleep`` should be fine to simulate work in your processes.

Comment: Are you entirely sure there is only one Python process? Did you filter out all the others or properly sort the ``top`` output? Are you sure your processes have actual work to do, and are not just waiting? Your example has low parallelism (at most 5 frames) and later processes can only work when previous processes have done some work.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The queues have a maximum size of one, so you can argue that there is no parallelism at all since `get` and `put` block by default.

Comment: There is also a possible stall condition in your code. If `q_detections.get()` blocks in `identify_from_q`, then `put_frame_on_q` will never be called again. I would suggest to run `put_frame_on_q` in the parent process in a `while`-loop after starting the other processes.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @MisterMiyagi, I added a filter to `top` and you are correct, I was not spotting the all the processes. It is creating three processes but the other two are not being used (the main at 100% one not at all, the other very little ~5%). I shall have to rewrite this. Ideally I want to use `Pool` with `apply_async` but with my limited experience I am struggling to wrap my head around that.